# Can we accomplish linking Microsoft SharePoint Link to Login to Atlassian Confluence

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

We'd like to have a link on our Sharepoint site that with one click could login to our Confluence account and navigate to a page on Confluence without having to type in our Confluence email and password. We use On-Premises Sharepoint with SSO (that is already setup). We would like to setup a shared Confluence account for authenticating to Confluence. Is this possible?